# $(...).tooltip is not a function

Tags: javascript, laravel, twitter-bootstrap

I have a project based on Laravel with Bootstrap, which also includes some packages like bootstrap select (https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/)

I think the error comes from this package, but I cannot get the tooltip to work.

Console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).tooltip is not a function
<anonymous> http://localhost/user/test:242
mightThrow http://localhost/js/app.js:42326
process http://localhost/js/app.js:42394
```

I'm also getting this warning:

```
Source-Map-Fehler: Error: request failed with status 404
Ressourcen-Adresse: http://localhost/js/app.js
Source-Map-Adresse: popper.js.map
```

http://localhost/user/test:242

```js
<script>
$(function () {
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
})
</script>
```

mightThrow http://localhost/js/app.js:42326

```js
returned = handler.apply( that, args );
```

process http://localhost/js/app.js:42394

```js
mightThrow();
```

bootstrap.js

```js
try {
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    window.bSel = require('bootstrap-select'); 
    window.highlightJs = require('highlightjs');
    window.ApexCharts = require('apexcharts');
    window.Cookies = require('js-cookie');
    window.sjcl = require('sjcl');
    window.ScrollProgress = require('scrollprogress');
    $.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.BootstrapVersion = '4.3.1';
} catch (e) {}
```

app.js

```js
require('./bootstrap');
require('highlightjs');
require('apexcharts');
require('js-cookie');
require('scrollprogress');
require('sjcl');
```

I was once getting it to work but I cant remember how I did it and when the tooltips were working, the bootstrap select wasnt working anymore.

I'm also using the Hyper Bootstrap theme: https://themes.getbootstrap.com/product/hyper-responsive-admin-dashboard-template/

Any idea how to solve that issue that BOTH, the select package AND tooltips working?

EDIT:
It works when I remove the jquery line in bootstrap.js, but the bootstrap select isnt working anymore. So jQuery may be loaded twice, but where do I find the second one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved the issue myself.

The issue was in app.js and bootstrap.js

I'll have to require the package in app.js by its full source:

```js
require('bootstrap-select/js/bootstrap-select.js');
```

and remove it in bootstrap.js (also the jQuery):

```js
    window.Popper = require('popper.js').default;
    //window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
    //window.bSel = require('bootstrap-select'); 
    window.highlightJs = require('highlightjs');
    window.ApexCharts = require('apexcharts');
    window.Cookies = require('js-cookie');
    window.sjcl = require('sjcl');
    window.ScrollProgress = require('scrollprogress');
    $.fn.selectpicker.Constructor.BootstrapVersion = '4.3.1';
```